# How to add a new statement to an existing SQS QueuePolicy from another template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I have 2 services with different Cloudformation YAML templates and want to add another policy to a queue policy defined in producer service (to allow consumer to receive and delete messages). However, my current solution simply overrides the existing policy instead of appending it (i. e., only consumer service role remains in the policy).

This is Cloudformation template SQS part for producer:

```
  ProducerQueuePolicy:
    Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Id: SQSPolicy
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            AWS:
            - !GetAtt ServiceRole.Arn
          Resource: !GetAtt ProducerQueue.Arn
          Action:
          - 'sqs:DeleteMessage'
          - 'sqs:ReceiveMessage'
          - 'sqs:ListQueues'
          - 'sqs:SendMessage'
          - 'sqs:GetQueueUrl'
          - 'sqs:GetQueueAttributes'
      Queues: [ !Ref ProducerQueue ]

  ProducerDeadLetterQueue:
    Type: 'AWS::SQS::Queue'
    Properties:
      QueueName: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-ProducerDLQ.fifo"
      FifoQueue: true
      ContentBasedDeduplication: false

  ProducerQueue:
    Type: 'AWS::SQS::Queue'
    Properties:
      QueueName: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-ProducerQueue.fifo"
      FifoQueue: true
      MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600
      ContentBasedDeduplication: false
      RedrivePolicy:
        deadLetterTargetArn: !GetAtt ProducerDeadLetterQueue.Arn
        maxReceiveCount: 9

# Outputs -------------------------------------------------------------------------
Outputs:
  ProducerQueueUrl:
    Value: !Ref ProducerQueue
    Export:
      Name: ProducerQueueUrl
  ProducerQueueArn:
    Value: !GetAtt ProducerQueue.Arn
    Export:
      Name: ProducerQueueArn
```

And this is Cloudformation for consumer:

```
#SQS policy configuration for consumer
  ProducerQueueConsumptionPolicy:
    Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Id: SQSConsumptionPolicy
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - !GetAtt ServiceRole.Arn
            Resource:
              Fn::ImportValue: ProducerQueueArn
            Action:
              - 'sqs:DeleteMessage'
              - 'sqs:ReceiveMessage'
              - 'sqs:GetQueueUrl'
              - 'sqs:GetQueueAttributes'
      Queues:
        - Fn::ImportValue: ProducerQueueUrl
```

What needs to be done to change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to merge the queue policies, write a cloudformation macro that reads a policy definition from the template and merges it with the existing queue policy. The macro gets given a json version of the template and you can manipulate it how you like in a lambda so you can check for an existing queue policy and update the template appropriately.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html

An alternative approach is just weaken the queue policy so that most operations are allowed by anything in the account. Then add permissions to whatever is reading and writing to the queue (eg lambdas) through separate roles. So the lambda doing the reading would use one role that allowed reading and the lambda doing the writing would use a different role that allowed writing.

Obviously that might not fit in with how you've arranged you're security so might not be suitable.

Comment: Guess I'll have to go in this direction (macros) because the different versions of the example from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46648346/amazon-aws-sqs-apply-queuepolicy-to-existing-queue still lead to either second policy not being applied or rewrite of the producer policy. Thank you!

Comment: Having had a think about it on the way to work, a custom resource would be the other approach. A custom resource would work better if you have a build pipeline deploying to multiple environments. Otherwise either way should work.

Comment: Yeah, it really looks interesting. Thanks again!